# need to help, child-component duplicate after click to link in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, command-line-interface

Work with child-component routes

```
const SignupRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'firstStep', component: FirstStepComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'secondStep', component: SecondStepComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'thirdStep', component: ThirdStepComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
];

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'service', component: ServicesComponent },
  { path: 'indoor', component: IndoorComponent },
  { path: 'invoice', component: InvoiceComponent },
  { path: 'report', component: ReportComponent },
  { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
  { path: 'shop', component: ShopComponent },
  { path: 'signup2', component: SignupComponent, children: SignupRoutes },
  { path: 'password', component: PasswordComponent },
  { path: 'settings/telephones', component: TelephonesComponent },
  { path: 'settings/password-edit', component: PasswordEditComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/login'}
];
```

My problem is duplicate child components which after clicking on the next step button not replace each other. I get list of child-component as in the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmdiK.png)
How cai I fix this problem?May be I need somehow to clean old child-components?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent },
```

to

```
{ path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
```

You need this when a route has an empty path but no child routes.

Comment: problem still exists

Comment: How does the link look like (how is it created)? Where is the link?

Comment: <button type="button" routerLink="/signup2/secondStep"  
     class="blue__button inputs__reg reg__inputs inputs__reg--
     button">Next step</button>

Comment: my link button created in each child-components to move between them

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - thanks for this information. It's valuable.

Comment: that's problem(I can't do it, cause I can't show even piece of code((May you can tell some solutions yet?May be I need somehow to clean old old component? If you don't know how to help yet then thank you for attention,really thank you